# How to turn on "helm-mode" for a specific function?

Tags: helm, completion, yasnippet

## The context

I've defined a big set of `yasnippet` snippets and sometimes I forget
the shortcut for those snippets. I've found out recently that
the function `yas-insert-snippet` can be used to insert a snippet by
writing its name and the completion list of the function lists all the
existing snippets.

I would like to use `helm` only for selecting an item from the
completion list shown by `yas-insert-snippet`. However, I don't want
`helm-mode` to be enabled because that would change the behavior of
all functions that show a completion list (e.g. `switch-to-buffer`,
`bookmark-jump`, `kill-buffer`, etc.).

I just want `helm-mode` to be enabled when executing the function
`yas-insert-snippet`.

I've found that the variable `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` can
only be used to turn off `helm-mode` for specific functions but I
would need to add all the functions to
`helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` using cons of the form
`(FUNCTION . nil)` if I want `helm-mode` to be disabled when executing
FUNCTION.

## The question

How can I toggle `helm-mode` for an specific function? I assume that
`helm-mode` is disabled by default since `helm` is not used for all
functions.

## Additional context

I've tried the following but it doesn't work. I wrote it
because I noticed that `helm-mode` is a variable.

```lisp
(let ((previous-helm-mode helm-mode))
  (helm-mode 1)
  (call-interactively 'yas-insert-snippet)
  (helm-mode previous-helm-mode))
```

Comment: You can't turn the mode off with a nil value. Try setting previous-helm-mode to `(or helm-mode 0)`.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to accomplish that

```lisp
(defun execute-with-helm (command)
  (if helm-mode
      (call-interactively command))
  (progn
    (helm-mode 1)
    ;; We call `unwind-protect' to ensure that `helm-mode' is
    ;; disabled even though `command' doesn't complete normally.
    ;;
    ;; Without `unwind-protect', if the user presses =C-g= while
    ;; `command' is being executed, then the entire function would
    ;; be exited and therefore, `helm-mode' wouldn't be disabled'
    (unwind-protect (call-interactively command)
      (helm-mode -1))))
```

Then, you can use that function as follows

```lisp
(execute-with-helm 'switch-to-buffer)
```

```lisp
(execute-with-helm 'kill-buffer)
```

```lisp
(execute-with-helm 'yas-insert-snippet)
```